# How do I install stemmer package in python

Tags: python

I'm running jupyter using python 3.9.7. I need to use stemmer package. So I wrote following command

```
!pip install PyStemmer
```

But I'm getting following message & stemmer is not installing

```
Collecting PyStemmer
  Downloading PyStemmer-2.0.1.tar.gz (559 kB)
  Building wheels for collected packages: PyStemmer
  Building wheel for PyStemmer (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for PyStemmer (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for PyStemmer
  Failed to build PyStemmer
  Installing collected packages: PyStemmer
  Running setup.py install for PyStemmer: started
  Running setup.py install for PyStemmer: finished with status 'error'
```

Can you help me to install stemmer?

Comment: Try again with `--verbose`

Comment: @Mattwmaster58 are you meaning !pip install PyStemmer --verbose

Comment: Try running this command `pip install wheel` and then run `pip install PyStemmer`

Comment: @RohithNambiar, after running `pip install wheel` I got `Requirement already satisfied: wheel in c:\users\0121e8744\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.37.0)` then the same error for `pip install PyStemmer`